Nesting in a Functional pseudo-class
Can a.label be refactored (e.g. as nesting) in the following Functional pseudo-classes, to avoid the repetition?
div.media:has(
  a.label[href*="/abc"],
  a.label[href*="/def"],
  a.label[href*="/xyz"]
) {
  color: #f50;
}


div.media:has(.label:is([href*="/abc"],[href*="/def"],[href*="/xyz"])) ?

@TemaniAfif That is also a solution.
